# Pure markdown files to html generator

Tags: markdown, hugo, static-site, metalsmith

We are trying to convert our documentation files (md files) into a static website.

We have been looking at Hugo, Metalsmith and other static site generators.

But we feel that all of them are forcing us to add custom markup or a lot of extra metadata (frontmatter) which we are not really keen on.

F. ex. we have links in the md files that refers to other md files. 
Release procedure 
For these links to work we have to alter the md code with custom code like relrefs for Hugo and so on. Why can't we just maintain the link code as pure markdown.

We fully understand that the added frontmatter solves a lot of issues and give us a lot of options – but we don’t really need them – we just want to keep it simple.

So is there any site generators that don’t require extra custom code for the linking and structure to work? Or have we misunderstood something within the generators that we have looked at?

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic here, but you can find a long list of options at https://www.staticgen.com/ and https://staticsitegenerators.net/

Comment: Sorry for that - I'm new to stackoverflow. 
But thx for the links - they give a nice overview of what's out there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy Metalsmith plugin to load default values into the "front matter" so you can avoid adding much/any special headers into your existing files...

https://github.com/woodyrew/metalsmith-default-values

Comment: This could solve some of the problems we had - thanks. But still not all that happy about the linking issues.